# How can I use set-builder notation for creating lists?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I am trying to formalize an algorithm using the [set-builder notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation).
Having an array B of values $d$:
$$
B = [d_1,d_2, \ldots,d_n]
$$
For instance, I want to define a new list $A$ containing the values $d$ that are greater than a value $h$. The order is important and there could be also values with the same distances. So the following expression using the set-builder notation is wrong:
$$
A = \{\ d_i \ |\ d_i  \in\ B , \ d_i >h \}
$$
Can I use the set-builder notation for creating list of values? So far I though this could be a solution, but I don't know if it is acepted:
$$
A = (\ d_i \ |\ d_i  \in\ B , \ d_i >h )
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ultimately notation is not so much about being technically correct, it is about being *understood*. Set builder notation is so standard, that any mathematically educated person reading it will understand what it means, which makes it a good notation (this is also what makes it meaningful to speak of "correct" and "incorrect" set builder notation).

Since you are not looking to define a set, set builder notation is not really what you are looking for. The question is: how can you succinctly express what you are going for without being confusing?

Your original notation
$$
A = (d_i \mid d_i \in B, d_i > h)
$$
is not standard. However, I would likely understand it if it was clear from context that $A$ should be an array (or sequence) and that the ordering of $A$ matters. Personally I think this notation could be improved by replacing $d_i \in B$ with $1 \leq i \leq n$; because $B = [d_1\ \ldots d_n]$, the fact that $d_i \in B$ is essentially redundant, and anyway $d_i \in B$ is not really standard notation when $B$ is not a set.

An equally formal definition of $A$ would be: "$A$ is the subsequence of $B$ consisting of all entries in $B$ which are larger than $h$". Since there is less possibility of misunderstanding in this English sentence than in the mathematical expression, this is arguably *more* formal, not less, even though it is written in natural language rather than in mathematical symbols.